# WebElement.click() doesn't submit the form

Tags: jakarta-ee, selenium, spring-security, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to make selenium test for spring security, and i followed many examples with no luck, i always end up with login fail:

```
public class LoginTest {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080";
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoginClass() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/MyAPP/login");

        final WebElement usernameField = driver.findElement(By
                .id("j_username"));
        usernameField.sendKeys("1");

        final WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By
                .id("j_password"));
        passwordField.sendKeys("123456");

        passwordField.submit();

        System.out.println("##################### URL: "
                + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        Assert.assertNotNull(driver.findElement(By.className("welcomeHome")));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

**ISSUE**: i am sure that entered username and password matches, and i can print them in loginFailureHandler and i see that they are correct (before encoding, should they be encoded or not in loginFailure ? )

anyway, i am using SHA encoding:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">          
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
         <password-encoder hash="sha"/>             
      </authentication-provider>   
    </authentication-manager>
```

can anyone tell me please why i alwyas get login fail ?

this is my login form:

```
<form action="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="post">

                        <h:inputText  id="j_username"  />
                        <h:inputSecret  id="j_password" />
                        <h:commandButton   id="loginBtn" />

 </form>
```

**UPDATE**: using button click, make login success but doesn't forward the user to home page, and he still in login page, `driver.getCurrentUrl()` will print **login**

```
WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By
            .id("loginBtn"));
loginBtn.click();
```

**UPDATE2**: i tried to forward the user to home page after login with no luck too, user still in login page.

```
WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn"));
        loginBtn.click();

        driver.get(baseUrl + "/MyAPP/home");
```

**UPDATE3**: when i replaced the button click with enter click, it works fine i don't know why

**OLD**:

```
WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn"));
loginBtn.click();
```

**NEW**:

```
passwordField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: The .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) solved a problem I was having with running WebDriver on Android.  For some reason .click() wasn't working for buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried clicking on the button instead of `passwordfield.submit()`?

```
WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By
            .id("loginBtn"));
loginBtn.click();
```

Comment: well this gives me another strange behavior, i updated the post.

Comment: The new problem is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_WebDriver_fails_to_find_elements_/_Does_not_block_on_page_loa).  Basically, Selenium cannot tell that your `click()` has triggered a page load and that it must wait before checking for new elements.  You can fix this by adding an [implicit wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#implicit-waits) `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` before the `click()`

Comment: I'm not sure whether it matters, but in the examples it tends to be after the instantiation of the `WebDriver`.  Once set, it will last for the life of the `WebDriver` instance.

Comment: i tried adding it in `@Before` with no luck, still no forwarding for home page after login.

Comment: I guess `getCurrentUrl()` does not respect the implicit wait.  Try moving it to after the `driver.findElement(By.className("welcomeHome"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace name by id

use the following snip:

```
final WebElement usernameField = driver.findElement(By.id("j_username"));         usernameField.sendKeys("1");
final WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.id("j_password"));         passwordField.sendKeys("123456");
```

Comment: sorry i posted wrong code, even with find by id, i gets same result.